# Quantum Typicality

Tags: information-theory, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Let $\rho, \sigma \in \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$ with $\text{supp}(\rho) \subseteq \text{supp}(\sigma)$, and spectral decomposition
\begin{align*}
\rho = \sum_{x}p_x |\psi_x\rangle\langle\psi_x| ~~\text{ and }~~ \sigma = \sum_{x}q_x |\varphi_x\rangle\langle\varphi_x|.
\end{align*}
For any integer $n$ denote by $y^n :=(y_1, ..., y_n)$, $q_{y^n} := q_{y_1}  ... q_{y_n}$, $|\psi_{y^n}\rangle := |\varphi_{y_1}\rangle \otimes ... \otimes |\varphi_{y_n}\rangle$, and for any $\epsilon > 0$ the subspace $T_{n , \epsilon} \subset A^n$ is defined as
\begin{align*}
T_{n, \epsilon} := \text{span} \left\{ |\Phi_{y^n}\rangle \in A^n: ~ \left| \text{Tr}[\rho \log(\sigma)] - \frac{1}{n} \log q_{y^n} \right| \leq \epsilon \right\}.
\end{align*}
Finally, denote by $P_{n,\epsilon}$ the projection onto the subspace $T_{n,\epsilon}$ in $A^n$.

(1) Show that $2^{n(Tr[\rho \log(\sigma)] - \epsilon)} P_{n, \epsilon} \leq \sigma^{\otimes n} \leq 2^{n(Tr[ \rho \log(\sigma)] + \epsilon)} P_{n, \epsilon}$.

(2) Show that for any $\epsilon>0: ~ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Tr[\rho^{\otimes n} P_{n,\epsilon}] = 1.$

---

**What I've tried so far:**

From the definition of the set $T_{n, \epsilon}$ we obtain $2^{n (Tr[\rho \log\sigma]-\epsilon)} \leq q_{y^n} \leq 2^{n(Tr[\rho \log\sigma]+ \epsilon)}$. Furthermore, we can decompose

$\sigma^{\otimes n} = \sum_{x}q_x |\varphi_x\rangle\langle\varphi_x| = \sum_{x \in T_{n,\epsilon}}q_x |\varphi_x\rangle\langle\varphi_x| + \sum_{x \in T_{n,\epsilon}^c}q_x |\varphi_x\rangle\langle\varphi_x|$. For those parts of the sum, where x is typical, we can use the derived inequality,

$\sum_{x \in T_{n,\epsilon}} 2^{n (Tr[\rho \log\sigma]-\epsilon)} |\varphi_x\rangle\langle\varphi_x| + \sum_{x \in T_{n,\epsilon}^c}q_x |\varphi_x\rangle\langle \varphi_x| \leq \sigma^{\otimes n} \leq \sum_{x \in T_{n,\epsilon}} 2^{n (Tr[\rho \log\sigma]+\epsilon)} |\varphi_x\rangle\langle\varphi_x| + \sum_{x \in T_{n,\epsilon}^c}q_x |\varphi_x\rangle\langle \varphi_x|$

which leads to

$2^{n(Tr[\rho\log\sigma] - \epsilon)} P_{n,\epsilon} + \sum_{x \in T_{n,\epsilon}^c}q_x |\varphi_x\rangle\langle \varphi_x| \leq \sigma^{\otimes n} \leq 2^{n(Tr[\rho \log\sigma]+\epsilon)} +\sum_{x \in T_{n,\epsilon}^c}q_x |\varphi_x\rangle\langle \varphi_x| $

For the left inequality we can omit the sum, as all $q_{y^n}$ are positive

$2^{n(Tr[\rho\log\sigma] - \epsilon)} P_{n,\epsilon} \leq \sigma^{\otimes n} \leq 2^{n(Tr[\rho \log\sigma]+\epsilon)} +\sum_{x \in T_{n,\epsilon}^c}q_x |\varphi_x\rangle\langle \varphi_x| $,

but I cannot do the same for the right inequality. I do not see how I can get rid of this term on the RHS.

---

So, I am stuck with the second inequality of (1) and I do not know how to prove (2), because I do not see any useful connection between the given set and $\rho$. I am grateful for any hints that might help to solve this problem!

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I don't think that the inequality $\sigma^{\otimes n}\leq  \alpha P_{n,\epsilon}$ is possible for any value of $\alpha$. If $\sigma$ is positive definite then so is $\sigma^{\otimes n}$. But $P_{n,\epsilon}$ is certainly not positive definite (for small enough values of $\epsilon$.)

Comment: @Luftbahnfahrer Thank you for your comments! For the second inequality in (1) I "feel" the same as you do. But I am still not convinced mathematically that the statement is wrong. Because I think one should understand this statement not for fixed $n$ but for fixed $\epsilon$. So, we choose some arbitrary but fixed $\epsilon$ and then we pick some $n$ that is large enough. So, for every arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ we find a (probably very large) $n$ such that the probabilities are bounded.

Comment: So, if my thoughts are correct, we should be able to find some $n$ such that almost all eigenvectors of $\sigma$ are in $T_{n, \epsilon}$. So, the statement should be at least 'close to be true'. I am not sure how to argue from 'close to be true' to 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: For (2). I am not very experienced with respect to typicality, so I just can use the definitions above to draw my conclusions. Therefore, it is very likely that I missed something. Nevertheless, isn't the $\rho, \sigma$ you give an example where it works? $Tr[\rho \log \sigma] =  \log(1/2)$ and $1/n \log( (1/2)^n) = \log(1/2)$. Hence, we have $|\log(1/2)-\log(1/2)| = 0 \leq \epsilon$. Therefore, independently of the chosen $\epsilon$ the span is already the whole space $A^n$. So, isn't your example one where the claim is true?

Comment: For (1), the statement is still wrong unless $P_{n,\epsilon}$ is the identity matrix. However, if we changed it to: $P_{n,\epsilon}\sigma P_{n,\epsilon} \leq 2^{n\operatorname{Tr}(\rho\log\sigma)+\epsilon}P_{n,\epsilon}$, then the statement is true. This is probably what is meant.

Comment: My old observation for statement (2) was wrong, since I was thinking about the "usual" definition of typical subspaces. Sorry about that! I deleted my old comment. The correct terminology for $T_{n,\epsilon}$ (what you are calling the "typical subspace") is this is the "relative typical subspace of $\rho$ with respect to $\sigma$." Note that $-\operatorname{Tr}(\rho\log\sigma) = \operatorname{H}(\rho)+\operatorname{D}(\rho\Vert\sigma)$, where $\operatorname{H}(\rho)=-\operatorname{Tr}(\rho\log\rho)$ is the von Neumann entropy and $\operatorname{D}(\rho\Vert\sigma)$ is the relative entropy.

Comment: A bit of searching on google and I found the paper with the original result. What you are looking for is Lemma 4 in [quant-ph/0307170](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0307170.pdf).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117171/discussion-between-pcalc-and-luftbahnfahrer).